# Walmart API- Existing Type error issue- Bulk Items Setup(multiple)

Tags: python-3.x, api, walmart-api

I am able to make API calls to Walmart API through a Postman the bulk items Setup(Multiple) A POST request Response in an Successfully comes in postman, but in Walmart FeedId seeing an error. I am try to another way through excel it's working fine and publish the product in Walmart Successfully. Through API it's not working not publish the product in Walmart can you fix the error. even though I seem to have everything correct.

```
**HTTP REQUEST**
[enter image description here][1]
[https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/feeds?feedType=item][1]

**METHOD**

POST


**HTTP RESPONSE STATUS**

200 OK

**HTTP RESPONSE BODY**

{
    "feedId": "18486EF565B046D88641274001003195@AU8BCgA",
    "additionalAttributes": null,
    "errors": null
}

**REQUEST HEADERS**

Authorization :  "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
WM_SEC.ACCESS_TOKEN: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: {my arbitrary text key}
WM_SVC.NAME: Walmart Marketplace
Accept: application/JSON

**POST PAYLOAD**
<pre><code>{
  "MPItem": [
    {
      "Item": {
        "sku": "xxxxxxxx",
        "ShippingWeight": "1LB",
        "price": " ",
        "productIdentifiers": {
          "productIdType": "UPC",
          "productId": "xxxxxxx"
        },
        "productCategory": "xxxxxxxx",
        "asin": "",
        "additionalProductAttributes": [
          {
            "productAttributeValue": "",
            "productAttributeName": ""
          }
        ],
        "additionalOfferAttributes": [
          {
            "additionalOfferAttributeName": "",
            "additionalOfferAttributeValue": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "MPItemFeedHeader": {
    "locale": "en",
    "sellingChannel": "mpsetupbymatch",
    "version": "1.0",
    "processMode": "REPLACE",
    "subset": "EXTERNAL",
    "Mart": "WALMART_US"
  } 
}</pre></code>

 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwaMJ.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be that `ShippingWeight` is invalid.

Their spec sheet says

```
"ShippingWeight": {
    "type": "number", 
    "title": "Shipping Weight (lbs)", 
    "minimum": 0, 
    "maximum": 10000000000000000, 
    "exclusiveMaximum": false, 
    "multipleOf": 0.001
},
```

You need to replace `ShippingWeight": "1LB",` with `ShippingWeight": "1",`

Also you don't need to send `additionalOfferAttributes` if its going to be empty, it is not required.